# How can I interpolate a Animated value to result into a boolean or a string in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native, react-animated

I happen to have an animation that goes from -1 to 1 and I want to translate those values into the following 2 strings:

**'Previous'** if the value is negative.

**'Next'** if the value is positive.

```
this.state.anim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-1, 0, 1],
    outputRange: ['Previous','', 'Next'],
})
```

**Q: How can I use the value that `this.state.anim` contains to decide wether we're going to the next screen or to the previous one.**

More info:

`this.state.anim` receives it's values from a `PanGesture` and I'm using `this.state.anim` for many other things as well so it would be a shame not to use it here too.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: No, and I don't think that is possible. 
Instead I just used 2 separate Labels, one for Previous, and one for Next, with 2 separate interpolations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a `react-native-reanimated` v1.x solution, you can use the Math helpers to force an interpolated value into a boolean, or like in the OP's case, into strings:

```js
const interpolated = Animated.interpolate(
  value,
  {
    inputRange: [-1, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
  },
);

const interpolatedAsInteger = Animated.round(interpolated);

const boolean = Animated.cond(
  interpolatedAsInteger,
  new Animated.Value(true),
  new Animated.Value(false),
);
```

This example uses `round()` to force the interpolated value into a 0 or 1. Then `cond()` allows us to return an `Animated` node of whatever value we want. In this case I used true/false, but these could be strings like "Next" and "Previous".

With more logic this approach can also handle the zero case, which should return an empty string.

[Docs for `cond()`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/cond)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I haven't tested that solution (since I'm no longer on that project) but it looks like it would work.

Comment: How would you do this with react-native-reanimated v3.x?